# How to store the next two lines using enumerate and next

Tags: python, iterator, enumerate

I have a file where a pattern is repeated every 4 lines. I would like to look at the file, and if the second line (within the 4 line block) is longer than 2000 characters, I would like to write the 4 line block to an outfile.

I should start by saying, I am a biologist not a CS, so I'm relatively new to coding. Im trying to accomplish my task using enumerate to count which line I am on, also enumerate is an iterable, so I believe that I can call the next function on it. When I run the block of code below however, I end up printing all four lines in the group, when theoretically, I should only be printing the third and fourth lines. However, when I run this code, I end up printing all of the lines. which is the confusing part.

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
     if i % 4 == 1:
         first_line = line 
     if i % 4 == 2:
        if len(line.strip()) > 2000:
            seq_line = line
            third_line = next(f)
            fourth_line = next(f)
            print(third_line)
            print(fourth_line)
        else:
            pass
```

Even if I try something simple, such as:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
     if i % 4 == 1:
         first_line = line 
     if i % 4 == 2:
         print(line)
         print(next(f))
```

I end up getting all of the lines, which I still dont understand.

Thanks.

Comment: `next(f)` is going to bias the line number because `enumerate` isn't aware of the manual iteration happening in the loop. Can you share some example input & expected output?

Comment: Your posted code prints only 2 lines out of every 5 for me.  The 5th line is because you incorrectly skip line 3 in every group with your superfluous `next` command.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother with using `enumerate` or `next` at all.

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:

    # keep going until we exhaust the file
    while True:
        # read the next four lines of the file
        line1 = f.readline()
        line2 = f.readline()
        line3 = f.readline()
        line4 = f.readline()

        # if any of the lines are completely blank, the file is exhausted
        if not line1 or not line2 or not line3 or not line4:
            break

        # if line2 is long enough, print the block
        if len(line2) > 2000:
            print (line1)
            print (line2)
            print (line3)
            print (line4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `re` module to find chunks of 4 lines ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ecXrNk/1)):

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
     open('file_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:

    for g in re.finditer(r'([^\n]+(?:\n|\Z)){4}', f_in.read(), flags=re.DOTALL):
        if len(g[0].splitlines()[1]) > 2000:
            f_out.write(g[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate()` also returns an iterator. You can assign that to a variable, then increment this with `next()` rather than incrementing the file iterator. This way the index `i` will be incremented properly.

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    lines = enumerate(f, 1)
    for i, line in lines:
        if i % 4 == 1:
            first_line = line 
        elif i % 4 == 2:
            if len(line.strip()) > 2000:
                seq_line = line
                _, third_line = next(lines)
                _, fourth_line = next(lines)
                print(third_line)
                print(fourth_line)
            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not ridiculously huge and memory isn't an issue, you *could* alternatively just read in the whole document, then use `for`'s to check only every 4th line starting with the second line (remember indexing starts at 0, so we check line #1, then #5, #9, etc.), without having to bother with `enumerate`, nested `if` statements, `next` statements, or modular arithmetic.

To ensure you have a full block of 4 lines to look at every time, you can iterate through the last line of every full block of 4 (line #3, #7, #11, etc.), then check only the line that comes 2 before this.  When you find a match, write all 4 lines.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(outputfile, "w") as g:
    for line_num in range(3, len(lines), 4):
        if len(lines[line_num - 2]) > 2000:
            g.write(lines[line_num - 3])
            g.write(lines[line_num - 2])
            g.write(lines[line_num - 1])
            g.write(lines[line_num])
```

The syntax of `range()` is `range(from, to, skip)`.  So more specifically, the `range(3, len(lines), 4)` command returns a list of all integers beginning with `3`, then going all the way to the number equal to the total number of lines that are in the document, but only taking every 4th integer. So it's the list `[3, 7, 11, 15, 19, ... ]` and so on until you run out of line numbers.